# JAVA validate an image and if validated upload aws

Tags: cxf, apache-tika

I want to validate an uploaded image, that file is an image or not.
For this I am using Tika Parser, it parses it correctly but I get input stream as empty after parsing.

```
public static FileType checkFileType(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException, SAXException, TikaException,
            InvalidArgumentException {

        ContentHandler contenthandler = new BodyContentHandler();
        Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
        Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
        ParseContext context = new ParseContext();
        parser.parse(inputStream, contenthandler, metadata, context);
        //inputStream.close();
        String contentType = metadata.get(Metadata.CONTENT_TYPE);
}
```

I am getting input stream from org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.multipart.Attachment
InputStream inputStream = attachment.getDataHandler().getInputStream();

Comment: Without any code, it's hard to be sure. Are you correctly buffering the image before passing it to Tika, so it's available to be re-used by the upload?

Comment: Where's the buffering for re-use? Tika will consume the whole input stream if that's what you give it, as it needs to read the whole file to process it!